# How to instantiate a class within an C++ implementation file?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am trying to make use of some features of a third-party tool written in C++ and thought to just create a make file and include the sources of the tool. That was easy enough, but then I ran into some class declarations that were nested in an implementation file (*.cpp).

The problem is, I would like to make use of those class declarations but not sure how. I have this *.cpp file in a library now and would like to include AClass in my app sources and link against this library.

Here is an example of how the file (cclass.cpp) in this package is laid out.

```
#include "cclass.h"

class AClass { ... };

int ClassC::getNumber() 
{
    AClass ac;
    int num = ac.useIt();

    return num;
}
```

Is there a way to include AClass in my app and have this app link against a library which has cclass.cpp in it?

Comment: I'm going to guess that classes declared in the implementation file and not a header are not meant for you to instantiate. They're probably implementation details that you don't want your code depending on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are class declarations (actually, definitions) in cpp-files then they are meant to be private and shouldn't be accessible by the user of the library. In short: you can't and shouldn't use such class in your app because this is what the library author(s) intended.

Comment: Declarations in the `.hpp` files and definitions in the `.cpp` filles sounds like pretty normal to me. Why shouldn't OP use such classes?

Comment: I kind of see your point, but in this case, the class is more of a helper and it makes no sense on why it would be protected. I just don't see the intended need here to be protected. In which case, I'm sure I could duplicate it, but ... was hoping for better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, first of all, only a forward declaration is a *class declaration* everything else is a *class definition* even without method definitions. Secondly, you can see in OP's example that there is a `class AClass` **definition** in cpp-file which means that there is no such definition in a header otherwise it would cause a multiple definition error.

Comment: I'm guessing that even if the definition of `AClass` were replicated in a fresh .hpp, it wouldn't be linkable because there's no particular reason why a compiler compiling cclass.cpp would make the implementation of `AClass` a linkable symbol. Would that be about right?

Comment: @Ender, only an author of the library can give you a rationale for this class being hidden. If you have the access to this library's source code you can easily modify and rebuild it to suit your needs which is basically the whole point of the open source.

Comment: @r3musn0x I though  `class AClass { ... };` was an attempt at forward declaration, but it probably isn''t.

Comment: @bazza, true ... I guess I was thinking duplicate it with a minor prefix addition to the name so it wouldn't really be the same class.

Comment: @bazza, actually it might be linkable if the class is not defined in an anonymous namespace. I don't really see a reason why would a compiler discriminate like that so that `ClassC` is linkable while `AClass` isn't.